# HttpPostedFileBase building on the fly issue in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to upload multiple files using MVC. On my form I have a treeview control that shows all files available in various directories that the user selects. I capture the files selected by the user into a variable the files can be 1:n.

on My form I have placed a div tag and then I try to inject input tags of type file into the div tag before attempting to post the form:

```
for (y = 0; y < selectedFiles.length; y++) {
    $('#serverContent').val($('#serverContent').val() + '<input type="file" name="files" value="' + selectedFiles[y] + '" />');
};
```

on My MVC model I have declared :

`public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files { get; set; }`

and my post method signature has:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(int serviceUserId, string folderId,IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

my form signature is:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Documents", new { area = "ServiceUser" })" method="post" id="filesubmission" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

in my controller after post files are empty. If I look directly on the Request object, files are also empty on there. I'm thinking it's probably the way I'm building the input tags on the front end, but it's difficult to see these.

Comment: Did you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `form` tag of your form ?

Comment: Only file tags are being created file are not being posted.

Comment: You cannot set the value of `<input type="file" ... />` element (it can only be set by the user selecting a file for security reasons). Its not really clear what your trying to do with your javascript `for` loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke My for loop is trying to build <input type='File'.... elements for each file that the user has selected from a treeview control. The selectedFiles variable defined is a string array holding the full path and filename of each file that was selected. The #ServerContent is just a <div> tag with that id.

Comment: That is not possible. Why are the file inputs in the treeview not just named `files` so that they are posted when you submit the form?

Comment: there aren't any file input's on the treeview.they are just nodes and the name of each node holds either the file name or  a directory name. I was thinking maybe I should just pass the file names to the controller and then just use a Stream Object instead, it's just that this way seems nicer and more in line with MVC

Comment: You obviously can't do that (and a file input cannot be set to a string value anyway). Imagine if you navigated to a site that included hundreds of file inputs with `value="c:\password.doc"` etc and started downloading your files :). The only way the value of a file input can be set is by the user interacting with the control to specifically select a file